# Sites using jquery, but there's no jquery in the code

Tags: jquery

I wanted to know how sites do their animations, loading content without loading the entire page etc, so I googled for sites using jquery and found this http://docs.jquery.com/Sites_Using_jQuery. When I looked at the code of several sites, I dint find any one of them using methods like fadein() fadeout() or like my plain and simple code

```
$.ajax({type: "POST",
url: "page.php",
data: data,
beforeSend: function(pager) {etc. etc.
```

Look at this site http://www.2minuteexplainer.com/ or take stackoverflow.com itself. They're all doing animations and page loading and everything else but not using fadein() fadeout() and other code like I posted above. How do they do this, and is there a way of getting a peek into their code.

Comment: `2minuteexplainer.com` include `http://www.2minuteexplainer.com/js3/jquery.composite.js`, which includes jQuery and lots of other plugins. Stack Overflow include `jQuery` and then include http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=7fea23de3996. Don't forget jQuery is only a library for JavaScript; there's other libraries around that let you fadeIn and fadeOut elements; and of course, you can do it in native JavaScript as well.

Comment: This is the first time I'm hearing of minified js. Any idea how to maxify whats minified so I could learn a few things from there?

Comment: `@`Norman: If you're using Chrome, You can bring up the Developer Tools (F12), go to the "Scripts" tab, find the script you want to un-minify and press the curly braces icon at the bottom of your screen, which should pretty-print the code. Alternatively you can use a tool such as http://minifymyjs.net; turn off the "Mangle" and "Misc" sections, turn "On" format, put in your code, and click "Go". (disclaimer, I wrote it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the website you gave as an example is actually "minimising" their JS code. Therefore, it could be that the methods like fadeIn() are obfuscated somewhat.

I wouldn't worry about this too much.

fadeIn() and fadeOut() in jQuery have been around a long time and are very good at their respective tasks. No reason to not want to use them that I can see.

On the other hand, you could also look at "animate()" in jQuery, which allows you to animate a specific CSS property. In the context of fading, they might animate on the "opacity" property.

jQuery actually have an opacity demo further down this page:
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

jQuery isn't the only JavaScript framework that you can use to do animations and ajax.

Also it is possible the sites have minified / packed and combined their JavaScript so it's not obvious that they could indeed be using the very techniques you mention.